# Labeling Bar Chart in CorePlot

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-plot

I have a horizontal bar chart using [Coreplot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) in which I have labels within the bar itself with white text
like this

[image: Long Bar]

However, when the bar is to short to contain the label I would like the text Black and not offset like this.

[image: Short Bar]

Is there anything available to check if the label is clipped or compare the wide of the label to the bar length? So far I have this

```
-(CPTTextLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter percentFormatter];
    NSDictionary *bar = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:index];
    NSDecimalNumber *xValue = [bar valueForKey:@"Value"];
    NSString *stringLabel = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:xValue];

    CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    whiteStyle.color    = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    whiteStyle.fontSize = CPTFloat(12.0);
    whiteStyle.fontName = @"HelveticaNeue-Medium";

    CPTMutableTextStyle *darkStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    darkStyle.color    = [CPTColor blackColor];
    darkStyle.fontSize = CPTFloat(12.0);
    darkStyle.fontName = @"HelveticaNeue-Medium";

    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:stringLabel];

    if (**isLabelClipped**) {
        plot.labelOffset = 2.0f;
        textLayer.textStyle = darkStyle;
    } else {
        plot.labelOffset = -2.0f;
        textLayer.textStyle = whiteStyle;
    }
    return textLayer;
}
```

**EDIT**
As Eric suggested I attempted to to get the screen size from the plotspace, my thinking was I would use the difference  between the xValue and the barsBase, so I added the following

```
NSDecimal plotPoint[2];
plotPoint[CPTCoordinateX] = xValue.decimalValue;

NSNumber *barBase = [self numberForPlot:plot
                                     field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase
                               recordIndex:index];

plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY] = barBase.decimalValue;
CGPoint dataPoint = [plot.plotSpace plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:plotPoint numberOfCoordinates:2];
NSLog(@"Data Point:%@", NSStringFromPoint(dataPoint));
```

But this gives values like

> {531.46951532736807, 57.166666666666664}

The barBase value (57..) looks to be the far left of the plot area and not the 0 axis as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the bar length (from the `xValue`), you can use the plot space to determine its size on screen. After creating the `textLayer`, check its bounds `size`. Compare the two and decide whether to position the label inside or outside the bar.

Comment: Thanks Eric, but I'm having difficulty with screen size of the bar, I edited my question to include my latest attempt

Comment: You need to call the `-plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint: numberOfCoordinates:` twice—once for the base value and once for the tip. Since you have horizontal bars, use the same y-value for both calls. The difference between the `x` coordinates of the resulting points is the length of the bar in pixels.